# Correct way to share a View between Android activities?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to be able to share a View between different Android activities. This view is a music player that I want to always be at the footer of every activity. I also want to be able to access it from any class, so I have it referenced statically from my MainActivity. The view is called `Player`.

My MainActivity will set it up....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public static Player player;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainActivity.player = new Player(this);
}
```

The Player class is made by inflating my `player.xml` file.

```
public class Player extends LinearLayout{
private ImageView previousButton, playButton, nextButton, playlistButton;
private TextView songTitle;

public Player(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    init(context);

}


private void init(Context context)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.player, this);

    this.previousButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerPreviousButton);
    this.playButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerPlayButton);
    this.nextButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerNextButton);
    this.playlistButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerPlaylistButton);
    this.songTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerSongTitle);

}
```

How can I share this across multiple activities? I have a lot of functions in my Player class that I did not list that I need to be able to access from any class, not just the activity classes, thus I though of going the static route and having it only initialized once.

Could someone help me in letting me know the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: You need to implement service for that. Write your functions in service class. start the service from your main activity and then call the functions from any of the activities in your application.

Comment: And to share your view,create a layout file for your player and include that layout file in each of the activity's layout files.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to initialize your `Player` UI once, consider using **[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** instead of Activities. You would be able to swap out various UIs in the top portion of your screen, while keeping your `PlayerFragment` active and untouched on the bottom. This would also mean you do not have to bind/unbind your UI to your audio service every time the user navigates to a different part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

For your concern you need to define a separate XML layout for that.

Now when you need to show that XML in another layout you may try like this ...

```
<include layout="@layout/your_music_layout"/>
```

Simply adjust at place where exactly you need this.

Secondly for accessing it's feature you should declare SUPER CLASS. This super class will be extended by all other classes. Some thing like this ..

```
Public class MainActivity extends SuperClass{

}
```

Here your super class will extend Activity which indirectly will be extended by rest of all classes in your app.

That's it. you are good to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is not to share a `View` across multiple activities. Each view belongs to one activity and you shouldn't try to share it. Each view is constructed by passing a `Context` to it and it's tied to this `Context`.

You can create a parent class for all your activities and put the necessary code in there. This way you'll be able to share the code but still create separate `View` objects.